# useCallback function issue in react

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, react-usecallback

In this code, the searchText is showing in the console from outside of the handleFetchExams function. Why searchText value is not coming inside the handleFetchExams function? Please help me to bring the searchText value inside the handleFetchExams function. Thank you.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
const { products, browseProductsQueryParams } = state;
const { searchText } = browseProductsQueryParams;
const { sort, level, filter, page } = state;
console.log(searchText);

 const handleFetchExams = useCallback(
async ({ reset }: { reset: boolean }) => {
  console.log(searchText);
  dispatch({ type: productCatalogActions.SET_LOADING, payload: true });
  dispatch({ type: productCatalogActions.SET_ERROR, payload: false });
  try {
    let query = "";
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
      query = `${query}&search=${searchText.toLowerCase()}`;
    }
    query = `${query}&sort=${sort}&level=${level}&filter=${filter}&page=${
      reset ? 1 : page
    }`;

    const data = await fetchExamsByLevel(query);
    dispatch({
      type: productCatalogActions.SET_DATA,
      payload: {
        quizzes: data.quizzes,
        endOfResults: data.quizzes.length < 12,
      },
    });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: productCatalogActions.SET_ERROR, payload: true });
  } finally {
    dispatch({ type: productCatalogActions.SET_LOADING, payload: false });
  }
},
[sort, level, filter, page, searchText]);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share CodeSandbox link so that we can understand it clearly? Possible issues might be that you're not calling `handleFetchExams()`